# How to solve this definite integral involving greatest integer function$?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Find the value of the integral $$\int_0^2[x^2-x+1]\:\:dx$$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

My work:

I calculated this integral normally and I got the answer as $\frac83$ and then rounding it off to the greatest integer, the answer came out to be $2$.

But this answer is wrong and the correct answer is $1$. The solution involved graph of the quadratic and then by the help of graph and diving the integral into three parts, he got the answer.

I want to know that is there any other method $($**not involving graphs**$)$ by which we can solve this as I'm not so well versed in graphs. Maybe there is a trick or two which we can apply here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that $$\int_a^b f(g(x))dx≠f\left(\int_a^b g(x)dx\right)$$ because that’s what you seem to have done, calculating the integral first and then taking its floor.

Comment: @insipidintegrator thanks....i really messed up things

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each $x\in[0,2]$,$$\lfloor x^2-x+1\rfloor=\left\{\begin{array}{l}0&\text{ if }x\in(0,1)\\1&\text{ if }x=0\text{ or }x\in\left[1,\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)\\2&\text{ if }x\in\left[\frac{1+\sqrt5}2,2\right)\\3&\text{ if }x=2.\end{array}\right.$$Therefore\begin{align}\int_0^2\lfloor x^2-x+1\rfloor\,\mathrm dx&=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2-1+2\left(2-\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)\\&=\frac{5-\sqrt5}2.\end{align}

Comment: Carlos Santos, $$x^2-x+1=\left( x-\frac {1}{2} \right)^2+\frac{3}{4}$$ and $$x^2-x+1 \ge 1 \iff x \le 0 or x \ge 1$$ .

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Indeed. And… ?

Comment: If we draw the graph, $\lfloor{x^2-x+1}\rfloor$ is $0$ when $0 \lt x \lt 1$ and it is $1$ when  $1 \lt x \lt 2$.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung Sure about that? If $x=1.75$, then $x^2-x+1=2.3125$, and therefore $\lfloor x^2-x+1\rfloor=2$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! Forget to check when the function is equal to $2$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

There is no trick. The integrand is a step function (the graph consists of horizontal segments). You have to figure out where they are and calculate the integral as the sum of areas of rectangles.

You don't have to do that with a graph but it's probably easier than fussing with algebraic cases.

You have to think before jumping to a solution. In this case automatically "calculating normally" (however you did that) doesn't work.

Comment: How do we divide the integral$?$ I mean how do we split it$?$

Comment: You look at the value of the quadratic at each point in the interval and round the value down to the nearest integer. For example, when $x=1/4$ the quadratic has value $1/4 - 1/3 + 1 = 3/4$ which rounds down to $0$. The important places are the values of $x$ where the rounded down integer jumps up or down. I really do recommend drawing the graph, even though you would rather use formulas.